# ScriptBundle+Optimization return unwanted number

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, minify

I'm using ScriptBundle and set EnableOptimizations to true.

My original script is

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 5000, pause: "hover" })
```

And the result from minification is

```
$(".carousel").carousel({interval:5e3,pause:"hover"})
```

Which make the carousel slides super fast! Any idea how to solve this problem? Any escape character should I use to avoid this 5000 turn to 5e3?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it make any difference if you specify the interval as a string `interval: "5000"` instead or is that not possible in the first place?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl string doesn't work but I just try disable optimization bootstrap js files and it works.. now I know it's not about the 5e3 thing that causes the speed. It's minifying of bootstrap js files   that cause the problem. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can minify bootstrap but a few rules:

Make sure you dont minify a minified version, Taking out the block comments /*   */   seems to make things less buggy.   and finally seperate everything out like so:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/jquery").Include(
            "~/assets/js/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.isotope.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.fancybox-{version}.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/assets/js/bootstrap.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js",
            "~/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/custom").Include(
            "~/assets/js/revolution.custom.js",
            "~/assets/js/custom.js"
            ));
```

I find that this method seems to calm the beast down and you get good results.  i also find that:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

These file are best done on there own, and cause major issues with the script bundling.

Comment: Yes, I did minify and minified version and that causes the problem. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Regarding the block comments at the beginning of bootstrap.js: jquery scrips end with sourcemap comments. The beginning of the block comment gets merged in at the end of the sourcemap comment, which disables the start of the block comment. This is where things go off the rails. I've found that you can bundle bootstrap.js unmodified, but it must be the first script in the bundle in order to deal with this issue.